# boost::filesystem::create_symlink not supported

Tags: c++, boost, symlink, boost-filesystem

I'm having a problem with this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        bfs::create_symlink("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt",
                        "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test_symlink.txt");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Calling the `create_symlink` function results in an exception being thrown with the message:

```
boost::filesystem::create_directory_symlink: The request is not supported: "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test_symlink.txt"
```

I've skimmed over Boost.Filesystem's `operations.cpp` file and found this:

```
  BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL
  void create_symlink(const path& to, const path& from, error_code* ec)
  {
#   if defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API) && _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600  // SDK earlier than Vista and Server 2008
    error(true, error_code(BOOST_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, system_category()), to, from, ec,
      "boost::filesystem::create_directory_symlink");
#   else

#     if defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API) && _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600
        // see if actually supported by Windows runtime dll
        if (error(!create_symbolic_link_api,
            error_code(BOOST_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, system_category()),
            to, from, ec,
            "boost::filesystem::create_symlink"))
          return;
#     endif

    error(!BOOST_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK(from.c_str(), to.c_str(), 0),
      to, from, ec, "boost::filesystem::create_symlink");
#   endif
  }
```

which suggests my `_WIN32_WINNT` might not have been high enough when compiling Boost. I've went and compiled Boost.Filesystem again but this time with `define=_WIN32_WINNT=0x601` added and I still get an exception with the same message. I've also tried defining `BOOST_WINDOWS_API` [which seems to be deprecated](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#Macros) but that resulted in compilation errors.

I'm using Windows 7, Boost 1.54.0 and `MinGW-x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev4` from [mingw-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure but I mean that the symlink is only supported on unix systems.